# Regex match strings based on a certain pattern

Tags: c#, regex, matching, multiline

How do I match a string using Regex based on a pattern with certain amount of characters to look for?

Example:

```
|V.2|58|
10001|W20101|W20101|G00001||||學徒劍盾|8|9|768||-1|1||||||||40002||||||1|14||2||40027|40028|40029|40030||2|22|113|||||||||||2|50|100|7|||||
10002|W30101|W30101|G00001||||學徒大斧|9|9|768||-1|1||||||||40003||||||1|17||3||40031|40032|40033|40034||2|26|142|||||||||||2|50|100|9|||||
```

If I know there's 58 vertical bars on each line then how would I set up a regex to match those strings based on the information I have? And as you also can tell the 58 at the top is the amount of vertical bars there should be in each string.

```
10479|I00208||G00005||||青鐵礦|29||0||-1|30||||3|||||||||100|5|1||54|$53$原始的礦石，整體泛著鐵青的色澤。

#IMG$NoticeIcon#30~45級的副本掉落或跟公會商人購買。
$7$能與其他材料結合，製作40級的合金材料。
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Another example is this. This one has multiple lines but is still within the 58 vertical bars' range.

Is there a way to match the pattern exactly based on the amount of vertical bars there is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not clear what you need exactly? can you explain more clear?

Comment: Is the only information you have the number of vertical bars? Or do you have any information what string should be between vertical bar X and X+1? (for verification)

Comment: `line.Split('|').Length == 58`?

Comment: Why would you even think of using regex for something a simple split can do? Forget about regex, you don't need it.

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear, I want to get the whole string on each line based on the amount of vertical bars there is. I couldn't think of anything else than regex since the split method is killed when dealing with a string with new lines like the example 2 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, yes, you can match this with a regex:

```
^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){58}*$
```

when compiled using `RegexOptions.Multiline`, will match from the first character of a line until exactly 58 bars (and any non-bar characters after that) have been matched.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lx4sKC/2).

It's completely context-unaware, though, so it absolutely relies on that number. In your example file, you'd need to exclude the first line from matching - otherwise those two bars will be included in the first match.

However, it looks like you're not using the right tool for the job. Maybe a CSV parser would be better suited? It appears your multiline data sample uses a quoting character in the entry that contains newlines, that is something a CSV parser can handle - and it will also handle cases where bars occur in a quoted field, something that this regex can't do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Tim. I haven't looked on what tools are actually more suited for this kind of job so I'll look it up. Ever since regex can match then i figured that it may do the job just fine, however it's very cumbersome.

Comment: Also what if there's 59 instead of 58? Just tested it out and it left it unmatched. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I take it that putting `59` in place of `58` doesn't work for you? Then you're pretty much out of luck - otherwise how should the regex tell whether a dataset is over if a line ends after 58 bars? Maybe the 59th entry is at the start of the next line - maybe the next record starts there...

Comment: It works although I have to do some other stuff to it. Thanks again. Also if I were to trim it so a line ends up being, say 50 after being matched, what would an example code look like for that?